# Getting 'pic-square' from user posts on the news feed using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the 50 x 50 profile picture for user posts on the news feed. It's easy to do this for likes and comments on posts but I can't figure out how to do it for the initial posts.
I also want to limit the query so that I only get results from "people" not "pages" and I only want unique results. In other words if a user appears twice on the feed I only need their picture once. I've played with the Graph API Explorer extensively and have looked all over the forums, here, as well as the documentation on the Facebook developers site. I would think this would be a common request so I'm not sure why it's been so hard to find.
My guess is that the syntax of the query would look something like this. Although this query doesn't work in the explorer.
`me/home/?fields=from.id.fields(pic_square),from&profile_type=user`

Comment: If only it were as easy as the query above. After more research it looks like I might have to use several nested FQL queries for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a lot of research and trial and error with FQL I figured it out. It's a series of nested queries and it returns an array with the urls of the pic-square images of the users whose posts appear in your news feed. The FQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT actor_id FROM stream WHERE filter_key IN (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me()))
```

I was not able to differentiate between user and page profile pics.